# Not able to override the `style.scss` in other component `scss` file

Tags: css, sass, angular7

Here is the `style.scss` - file

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_functions.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/_variables.scss';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/mixins/_breakpoints.scss';
@import 'global.scss';
@import "~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap";
@import "~angular-calendar/css/angular-calendar.css";

$grid-breakpoints: (
    sm: 767px,
    md: 768px,
    lg: 1024px
);

$container-min-widths: (
  sm: 767px,
  md: 768px,
  lg: 1024px
);

//resets;-

html,body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    height: 100%;
}
.wrapper.container-fluid{
    min-height: 100%;
    padding:0;
    margin: 0;
}

.btn:focus,.btn:active {
   outline: none !important;
   box-shadow: none;
}

@include media-breakpoint-up(md) {

    .hidden-md-up{
        display: none;
    }

}

@include media-breakpoint-down(sm) {

    .hidden-sm-down{
        display: none !important;
    }

}

.cal-has-events {
    background: #ccc; //works.
}
```

But when i modify the same class name from the `layzy-load` component css file, it's not works. i tried like importing `style.scss` in my lazy component scss file like, and tried to override the color of `cal-has-events` but not works!!  as well not getting any error. how to override the `style.scss` file in other component `scss` files?

```
@import 'styles.scss';



.cal-has-events{
    background: #00f;
    border:1px solid red;
}

.cal-day-open{
    background: #ffcccc; 
}

.cal-has-events {
    background: green !important; //not works!!
}
```

so, is that mean I need to write all overrides in `style.scss` itself. any one help me to sort this issue?

Answer (score 0):

Adding `encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None` - in the component works now.